# Best way to update SQL tables while querying it

Tags: mysql

So I have a MySQL table where it needs to get updated on a daily basis and the structure look like the following:

```
siteid    user  proportion
1000      1     0.1
1000      2     0.5
1000      3     0.4
```

Problem is that other parts of the code need to access this table while its being updated while the update might take several minutes everyday. This is what happens on a everyday:

- A task runs around 8am EST everyday to update the above table based on yesterday's data. This update might take up to half an hour.
- Users should have access to this table anytime to get the most recent updates

I have came up about the following ideas but pretty sure none of them would for work me:

- Create a temp table to access it while updating the main table: this does not sound like a good idea since there are five of those tables and not feasible to switch between temp and main table.
- Put a halt on all operations while the table being updated which is impossible since other code accessing the tables must be always up and running.

I would be very grateful for any help toward any possible solutions for this. I know this is broad and there might not be any right or wrong answers, mostly interested in your experiences with similar situations.

NOTES:

1. There tables have millions of rows stored in them.
2. I am using MySQL here and as mentioned before not able to lock transactions since everything must be live.
3. Backend code is written in python

Comment: You could lock the table until each transaction is done?

Comment: What are you expecting for an answer here? This is incredibly vague.

Comment: @SeanLange I know that this is a broad question but I am basically looking for any leads toward a possible solution. Right now investigating options like using a cache rather than a temp table and update the cache as needed but as I said there might be no right or wrong answers here. Looking for others experiences

Comment: The problem is that this is so vague the possibilities are nearly endless because there isn't much detail. There are many way this could be solved and they all depend on a lot of information we don't have.

Comment: @SeanLange I will update the question again and provide as much information as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this maybe this way?

1. Have two tables with the same structure, names ending in _A and _B.
2. Have a view that can be toggled on the fly to point to _A or _B (In Oracle we would use a synonym).

In your update procedure:
1.  Copy data from _A to _B.
2.  Point view to _A (update the view).
3.  Do Updates to _B
4.  Point view to _B (update the view).

Next time you run, you'll repeat the process, but the _A references become _B and vice versa.  You might want to way to track whatever the "current" tables are (_A OR _B).